# NVC has changed my visa class, how can i get it corrected?

Tags: visa, immigration

I (Petitioner-LPR) filed for I-130 along with an I-130A for my wife(Applicant), which was approved. I also received my NVC case number . I logged into the CEAC and paid the first fee for affidavit of support. I logged in again the following week to check status and the whole page was different, stating that due to numerical limits, there isn't a visa available.
Very alarmed, I noticed the Visa class was F24 instead of F21. How can i get this corrected?